# PhpStorm not understanding custom tags correctly

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm

Out of nowhere, PhpStorm has decided to misunderstand custom tags are and as a result doesn't format the code correctly.

I'm editing a .vue file - here's a short snippet of what it should be formatted like:

```
<template>
    <auth-layout>
        <h2>{{ __('register.content.heading') }}</h2>
        <p>{{ __('register.content.copy') }}</p>
    </auth-layout>
</template>
```

However, PhpStorm complains that the `auth-layout` tag is never closed. Then when running the reformat action, anything underneath `</auth-layout>` gets messed up.

Does anyone know why this is happening and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok as is tradition, I have solved this immediately after posting this question. My auth-layout tag has a `lang=""` attribute which was completely confusing PhpStorm. Removing it fixes it.

Comment: could you provide more info on this? what does your component definition look like? custom attributes shouldn't normally break the syntax highlighting